# How to sum up a list of counts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, sum

Apologies if I am going about the wring way for this. But I have the following code and want to have a sum of it rather than two separate numbers:

```
    <% @all_users.each do |i| %>
        <%= i.liked_recipes.count %>
    <% end %>
```

The output for this code is as follows:

```
12 4
```

What I would like the output to be would be the sum:

```
16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also:

```
<%= @all_users.sum { |u| u.liked_recipes.count } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some way to keep track of the count:

```
<% total = 0 %>
<% @all_users.each do |i| %>
    <% total += i.liked_recipes.count %>
<% end %>
<%= total %>
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way of doing this would be to use `inject`

```
@all_users.inject(0) { |result, i| result + i.liked_recipes.count }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `@all_users` is not loaded other than for these recipe counts then it is probably best to let the database do the counting:

```
LikedRecipe.where(:user_id => @all_users.select(:id)).count
```